# How to get file path when opening a file from Finder

Tags: c++, macos, finder

I have built a C++ cross-platform application and am struggling with how to get it to work correctly on macOS.
So far, I'm able to run the application manually with the command `open /Applications/myApp.app --args /path/to/myFile.ply`.
I have associated all `ply` files with my application but when I double click on it in the finder, the file path is not in `argv` argument list.
How can I get the double-clicked file path in my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an event loop, normally done using the `NSApplicationMain` function.  Then you need to receive an Apple Event telling what file(s) to open.  It will be much easier if you are willing to use some Objective-C or Swift, rather than pure C++.  In Objective-C, you'd make an object that conforms to the `NSApplicationDelegate` protocol and that implements a method `application:openURLs:` or `application:openFile:`.

Comment: This seems to be the solution. I use a cross-platform library that create a `NSApplication`: `NSApplication* application = [NSApplication sharedApplication]; [application run];`. How do I connect my delegate to the NSApplication?

Comment: Found: `MyDelegate* deleg = [MyDelegate alloc]; [NSApp setDelegate:deleg];`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

@JWWalker has explained how to solve your problem by altering your code to cope with the macOS GUI environment. Here is a different approach which avoids messing with your C++. Pick the one that suits you needs best.

If your cross-platform application is designed to run from the shell prompt you might want to run it within the macOS `Terminal` app. You can do this using a small *AppleScript* application which accepts the file paths passed by the Finder and invokes the Terminal app to run your C++ code.

To do this open `Script Editor`, you will find it inside `Utilities` in `Applications`. Enter the following:

```
on open passedItems
    set convertedPaths to ""
    # convert passed macOS paths to posix paths
    repeat with nextItem in passedItems
        set posixPath to the POSIX path of nextItem # convert macOS alias to posix path
        set convertedPaths to convertedPaths & " '" & posixPath & "'" # place in quotes to protect any spaces
    end repeat
    tell application "Terminal" # open (if required) and activate Terminal
        activate
        do script "echo " & convertedPaths # just run echo - use the path to your C++ binary instead
    end tell
end open
```

If you can program in C++ you can probably figure that out, if not search for AppleScript and all will become clear.

Now save this as an application, for this demo it was saved in `/tmp/bridge` (aka `/private/tmp/bridge` on macOS) as "Bridge.app".

Now create some test files with a suitable extension, e..g something like:

```
$ cd /tmp/bridge
$ touch a.bridgeDemo 'b c.bridgeDemo'
```

From Terminal you can open `/tmp/bridge` in a Finder window using:

```
$ open /tmp/bridge
```

In the Finder select any of your test files, do a `Get Info` and set the file to open with Bridge and then hit `Change All...`

Now try it: select the test files in the Finder and open them. You should see Terminal open/activate and show you something like:

```
$ echo  '/private/tmp/bridge/a.bridgeDemo' '/private/tmp/bridge/b c.bridgeDemo'
/private/tmp/bridge/a.bridgeDemo /private/tmp/bridge/b c.bridgeDemo
$
```

Now edit the AppleScript to run your compiled C++ instead of `echo` and save it in a suitable location. HTH